# if /else statement not working in android app

Tags: android

I am writing an app that takes two user inputs and matches them to data stored in a database and displays the corresponding data(row) from the user inputs in a textview.

The `if` statement works perfectly alone `if d condition is true`. It however stops working if I add the `else` statement.

The `else` statement is executed if d statement is `true` or `false`

```
    String name = Jasonobject.getString("name");
    String name1 = Jasonobject.getString("name1");
    String db_detail = "";

    // match user input with database and display corresponding row in
    // "detail" textfield
    if (et.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(name)
            && et1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(name1)) {
        db_detail = Jasonobject.getString("detail");
        text.setText(db_detail);
        break;

    } else {

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "NOT AVAILABLE";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
        break;
    }
```

Comment: you mean, the code under the 'else' statement always execute even if the  condition is true? what do you mean by "stops working"? did it crash?

Comment: Check the brackets,  try using 2 if's or else if..

Comment: "stops working" as in d 'if' statement is no longer executed even if the condition is true

Comment: Possible duplicate of [if /else statement not working in android app (else statement always executed)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31761525/if-else-statement-not-working-in-android-app-else-statement-always-executed)

Answer (score 0):

The `else` statement cannot run if the `if` statement is true at any cost.
Try to clean your project and re-compile it. Also are you executing this code in an loop, if not then you should get a misplace break error.