# if /else statement not working in android app (else statement always executed)

Tags: java, android

I am writing an app that takes two user inputs and matches them to data stored in a database and displays the corresponding data(row) from the user inputs in a `TextView`.

The if statement works perfectly alone if the condition is true. It is however not executed even if the condition is true if I add the else statement.

The else statement is always executed if the statement is true or false

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
    // ambil data dari Json database
    try {
        JSONArray Jarray = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject Jasonobject = null;
            //text_1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt1);
            Jasonobject = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);

            //get an output on the screen
            //String id = Jasonobject.getString("id");
            String name = Jasonobject.getString("name");
            String db_detail="";

            if (et.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                db_detail = Jasonobject.getString("detail");
                text.setText(db_detail);
                break;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            }
        }
        this.progressDialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flag variable to check whether user is available or not, and print your message after for loop.

```
boolean available=false;

JSONArray Jarray = new JSONArray(result);
for(int i=0;i<Jarray.length();i++)
{
    JSONObject Jasonobject = null;
    //text_1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    Jasonobject = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);

    //get an output on the screen
    //String id = Jasonobject.getString("id");
    String name = Jasonobject.getString("name");
    String db_detail="";
    if(et.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) 
    {
        db_detail = Jasonobject.getString("detail");
        text.setText(db_detail);
        available=true;
        break;
    } 
}

if(!available)
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 2):

you never loop entirely on `Jarray`. If a the first iteration `et.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(name)` is false, and the else branch is executed, you `break` immediately.

```
try {
   JSONArray Jarray = new JSONArray(result);
   for(int i=0;i< Jarray.length(); i++) {
      // other code
      if(et.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            db_detail = Jasonobject.getString("detail");
            text.setText(db_detail);
            break;
      }
   }
   if (TextUtils.isEmpty(db_detail)) {
      // show toast
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using:

```
else if(!et.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(name))
```

Comment: While the code may answer the question, it would be better to explain _how_ it works and _why_ to use it.